# How do I clear an ArrayList?

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I have the following code in `ThisClass`:

```
static ArrayList<MyClass> classlist;
```

If I call:

```
ThisClass.classlist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
ThisClass.classlist.add(object);
```

And then call this line again:

```
ThisClass.classlist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Will it reset the `ThisClass.classlist` list, i.e. the classlist list will no longer contain object?

Comment: yes sure! What else would you expect?

Comment: You are speaking of `ArrayLists` not `arrays`. If there is no other reference to the *old* `Arraylist`, it will be garbage collected.

Comment: Yes your right, it is an arraylist not array,

Comment: You can also call .clear(). I recommend this over setting the arraylist to a new array as it's clearer what your goal is even if both approaches have the same outcome. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#clear()

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Here's an illustration:

### Code 1: Creating the ArrayList and Adding an Object

```
ThisClass.classlist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
ThisClass.classlist.add(object);
```

Results into this:

[image]

### Code 2: Resetting through Re-initialization

```
ThisClass.classlist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

Results into this - you're resetting it by making it point to a fresh object:

[image]

### Code 3: Resetting by clearing the objects

What you should do to make it "no longer contain an object" is:

```
ThisClass.classlist.clear();
```

Clear loops through all elements and makes them *null*. Well internally the ArrayList also points to the memory address of its objects, but for simplicity, just think that they're being "deleted" when you call this method.

[image]

### Code 4: Resetting the entire classlist

If you want to make it "no longer contain an ArrayList" you do:

```
ThisClass.classlist = null;
```

Which means this:

[image]

Also, take note that your question's title mentions "static ArrayList". `static` doesn't matter in this context. The result of your problem will be the same whether the object is static or not.

Answer (score 6):

Calling

```
ThisClass.classlist = new ArrayList<MyClass>();
```

**does will** clear the `ThisClass.classlist` array (actually, will create a new `ArrayList` and place it where the old one was).

### That being said, it is much better to use:

```
ThisClass.classlist.clear();
```

It is a way clearer approach: shows your true intention in the code, indicating what you are really trying to accomplish, thus making you code more readable/maintainable.

Answer (score 2):

Correct.

Technically, you do not *clear* the `ArrayList` doing so, you actually instantiate a new empty `ArrayList`.